# How to configure the validation to use "is-invalid" class for invalid inputs

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-core, bootstrap-5, razor-pages

By default validation in ASP.NET Core for inputs uses class `input-validation-error` but bootstrap 5 uses `is-invalid`.

I found some solutions for this:

- Create the styles
- Use jQuery.validate.unobtrusive and configure the defaults by setting up `validClass` and `errorClass`

Is there a way to configure the system to tell it which class to use or is this hardcoded?

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap 5 only use the `.is-valid` and `.is-invalid` classes as fallback for server-side validation ... i.e., server side sets that class. The Bootstrap JS uses the `:valid` and `:invalid` pseudo-classes.

Not sure if you're looking for server side or client side --- either way read up on how validation works here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/forms/validation/

Also read up on Migration here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/migration/#utilities-1

If you want to create your own CSS, e.g. a `.input-validation-error` you can use the `form-validation-state` mixin, and a variation of the `$form-validation-states` map. SCSS is here: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/main/scss/mixins/_forms.scss